# Long Polling in Python Flask with SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, long-polling

I'm working on a project using python under the flask framework. I'm also using SQLAlchemy to do all DB transactions.

I'm doing long polling to check for new entries in a db table. I'm having a problem with SQLAlchemy

Comparing datetimes doesn't seem to be working. An explanation that would make sense is that SQLAlchemy is caching results, but from what I read online this wouldn't be the case.

Here's my code (Apologies for the poor formatting can't get it right here on stackoverflow):

```
@app.route('/poll')
def poll():
now = datetime.utcnow()
print(models.dump_datetime(now))

timeout = time.time() + 60*1
while time.time() <= timeout:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    db.session.expire_all()
    check = AuditLogEntry.query.filter((AuditLogEntry.datetime >= now) 
    & ((AuditLogEntry.action == "action1") | (AuditLogEntry.action == "action2")))
    if(check.count() > 0):
        for c in check:
            print(c.to_dict())
        break

return "DONE"
```

So when the poll() function is first called, it records the time as a datetime. It then searches the database for any rows that have a later datetime than `now`. If it finds one, it should print it to the console, and break the loop.

However, to put it simply it doesn't work. When a new row is added, and the time is after the time stored in `now`, it doesn't notice it.

Also, when I test to make sure the `now` is correct, and comparable to the datetime in the `AuditLogEntry.datetime with the following code, I can print the count of`test` and it is the number of rows in my table. So it works.

```
 test = AuditLogEntry.query.filter((AuditLogEntry.datetime < now) & ((AuditLogEntry.action == "action1") |
                                                                         (AuditLogEntry.action == "action2")))
print(test.count())
```

db.session.expire_all() doesn't seem to be working. The result set doesn't seem to be changing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the line `db.session.expire_all()` and I added `db.session.commit` after the SQLAlchemy query, and it works.

I'm not entirely sure why it works, I'd love if someone could explain it to me :)